# Using a junction table with its own relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm creating an app that has a `User` and a `Plugin` model. A user can have multiple plugins and a plugin can belong to multiple users, which I've implemented using a junction table.

```
class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_plugins
  has_many :users, through: :user_plugins
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_plugins
  has_many :plugins, through: :user_plugins
end


class UserPlugins < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plugin
end
```

However, I then want to store arbitrary data for each user plugin (for example, things like api keys, options etc that can differ for each plugin.).

My initial approach was to have a `user_plugins_options` that joined on `user_plugins`, but I can't seem to get this to work correctly.

```
class UserPluginOptions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_plugins
end
```

My question, how should I go about approaching this to best work with ActiveRecord?

Comment: What problem are you running into exactly? Your approach should work, although I'm not sure there's a need to split the options out into a separate table unless you're planning some sort of polymorphic plugin option model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misnamed your class, as the table is user_plugins but the model is `UserPlugin`.  It’s plausible you are running into issues because of this.

Agree with Alex.  Why don’t you create a json field on `UserPlugin` called options and keep a hash of plugin specific values here.

If you must have another table, you should add a `has_one :user_plugin_option` to your `UserPlugin`